# How to show/hide a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently making a registration page for a site and need to show a typical password confirmation message. How would I make a script to hide and show a div?

This is as far as I've got:

```
<html><head>
<script language="javascript">
function correctpassword()
var password="password"
var confirmpassword="confirmpassword" 
if (password1 != password2)
{
showcss="unconfirmed"
}
else
{
showcss="confirmed"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<u>Personal Details</u>
First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname">
Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname">
Date of Birth:
Gender: Male Female
<u>Login Details</u>
Email Adress:<input type="text" id="email">
Username:<input type="text" id="username">
<!--check avalibility-->
Password:<input type="text" id="password">
Confirm Password:<input type="text" id="confirmpassword">
<!--Javascript if "password" doesnt equal "confirm password" showcss passwords don't match-->
<button type="button" onclick="correctpassword()">Display Date</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PS:The variables may be wrong.

Comment: You question doesn't make any sense. What do you mean by show some CSS?

Comment: What do yo mean with *hide and show some CSS*?

Comment: Sadly these are all great answers so I'm just going with the simplest. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about hiding / showing a `div`, `span`or other similar element in HTML, you can use the [jQuery JavaScript framework](http://jquery.com). For example:

```
$('#element_to_show').show();
$('#element_to_hide').hide();
```

You can trigger the hide / show via events, e.g. key press or user leaving the input element, in jQuery as well.

Answer (score 0):

Control your styles and appearance with className property that applied to class markup attribute.
Try to avoid .style property of the elements and add/remove some classes instead. It will give you more control and simplify maintenance in the future.

in css:

```
.show{
  display:block;
}

.box{
  display:none;
}
```

in html:

```
<div id="passConfirm"></div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

in your script:

```
var confirmEl,
    confirmBox;
confirmEl = document.getElementById('passConfirm');
confirmBox = document.getElementById('box');
confirmEl.addEventListener('click', showBox, false);

function showBox () {
  confirmBox.className += ' show';
}
```

As mentioned, you can use some libraries that helps to work with DOM or write your own functions helping to add and remove some classes, check for hasClass method etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone, hence the short answer.
Easiest way is to get the id of the element like `document.getElementById` and place that into a variable.
Then use the style property like

```
Obj.style.display = "none";
```

To hide it.